# Windows 10 Notification Center doesn't open the link

Tags: windows-10, notifications, notification-area

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 and I discovered that there's a Notification Center. In short, I enabled Facebook push notification and I receive them properly with no problem, but when I open the Notification Center and click on the notification that I received, *it does nothing*, it doesn't open the link, and the notification goes away.

Answer (score 0):

After a Windows update, I encountered a similar issue. Apparently, *parts of* the *Notification* system now run as a *Background app*, and this can be set in the *Privacy* Control Panel (CPL).

[image: Background Apps CPL]

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and select the *Privacy* CPL.
- Scroll down to *Background apps*
- Enable `Let apps run in the background`.
- Enable `Settings`.
- If Facebook or your preferred browser appear in the list of apps, enable them. [*Edge* is off on my settings because it is not the [preferred browser.]
- Enable `Windows Security`, particularly if you use *Defender*.

Also, third-party privacy tools such as [O&O ShutUp10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10), shown below, can *also* disable background apps. Allow *App Notifications*.

[image: ShutUp10 Privacy Settings]

Hopefully, *Notifications* will work again. Post here if it works, or you found another solution.

Comment: To be clear, I don't have the Facebook app, I only have the chrome browser which is my default browser. And all my applications are set to on.